# How to create a geography and double precision database columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I would like to create a table like with this postgresql query. How to made a rails migration with a DOUBLE PRECISION and Geography column  ?

```
CREATE TABLE poi_trace (
    poi_id BIGINT REFERENCES pois(id),
    trace_id BIGINT REFERENCES traces(id),
    geog GEOGRAPHY(Point, 4326),
    advance_on_trace DOUBLE PRECISION,
    active BOOLEAN
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run custom sql in migrations

```rb
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TABLE poi_trace (
        poi_id BIGINT REFERENCES pois(id),
        trace_id BIGINT REFERENCES traces(id),
        geog GEOGRAPHY(Point, 4326),
        advance_on_trace DOUBLE PRECISION,
        active BOOLEAN
      );
    SQL
  end
 
  def down
    drop_table :poi_trace
  end
end
```

[Read more about this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods)